# How to find 'bad' calculated memebers in a SSAS cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas

Does anyone know a way to have BIDS or SSAS automitically check the correctness of any calculated memebers that have been declared?  We have a large number of them, and the measure names have been subject to some renaming, and now we keep getting errors at run-time where the names no longer match up.

I was suprised that there seems to be no checking of the correctness of the calculated memebers being done.  Does anyone know a way to force such checking, or a generic strategy we could use for checking this up-front?

Answer (score 0):

Silvere presents a simple console app solution for checking partition sizes [here](http://slhermite.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/get-size-of-every-partition-of-ssas.html)